# Highest stack of rectangles

Tags: time-complexity, runtime-analysis

Suppose we have a set of $n$ dimensional rectangles $R = \{(x_{i,1}, \ldots, x_{i,n}), i \in 1 \ldots k\}$. We want to create the highest stack in say the first dimension such that each side of the rectangles form a monotonically increasing sequence. More formally from the $l$-tuples satisfying this

$$
\max_{l: (j_{1}, \ldots, j_{l}), j_{i} \in 1 \ldots k, j_{q} = j_{p} \iff q = p}{\forall q \in 1 \ldots l - 1, \forall p \in 1 \ldots n:  x_{j_{q}, p} < x_{j_{q + 1}, p}}
$$

take the one with the maximal $\sum_{i = 1}^{l}{x_{j_{i}, 1}}$ or just simply calculate this maximal value.

What's the algorithmic complexity of this? For $n = 1$ we can think of this as a weighted [LIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence). Is there a better approach than just sorting it on the first dimension and trying to find the longest increasing sub sequence for all dimensions?

Comment: I don't know, but can you reduce Longest Path to this problem?  If you consider the graph where you have an arc from $a$ to $b$ if rectangle $b$ is greater than $a$ in each side.

Comment: I would guess it's NP-hard.

Comment: Ah ok, the longest path in a graph makes sense. If you create a graph where the nodes are the rectangles and edges go between 2 if the target is smaller than the source we get a DAG. We can do topological sorting on this and use dynamic programming starting from the source nodes to find the longest paths ending in each node. And the maximum of these values is the answer. I think it's $O(V + E)$. Is there something I miss here?